# How to create an effective index for following query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have converted a web server access_log to a mysql table, it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `access_log` (
`timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`visitorid` int(11) default NULL,
`url` int(11) default NULL,
`params` int(11) default NULL,
`status` smallint(3) NOT NULL default '0',
`bytes` int(20) NOT NULL default '0',
`referrer` int(11) default NULL,
`refparams` int(11) default NULL,
`useragentid` int(11) default NULL,
`keywords` int(11) default NULL,
`country` char(3) default '',
`crawl` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`sessionid` int(11) default NULL,
KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
KEY `visitorid` (`visitorid`),
KEY `url` (`url`),
KEY `referrer` (`referrer`),
KEY `keywords` (`keywords`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=1;
```

I have a query that produces a "Most Popular Pages" report for a certain date range, an example looks like this:

```
select url,
count(distinct visitorid) as visitors,
count(*) as hits 
from access_log where 
timestamp >=1270072800 and timestamp <=1272664799 
and crawl=0 
group by url order by visitors desc limit 100;
```

This query gets pretty slow when there are a lot of records in the table.

Depending on the timestamp range relative to the total number of records in the table, the optimizer says it will either use the 'timestamp' or the 'url' key. But, it always mentions 'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort'

Is there any way I could create a combined index that would improve the execution time of this query?

I've tried the following combinations, but the optimizer seems to ignore them:

1. idx(timestamp,url,visitorid,crawl)
2. idx(url,visitorid,crawl,timestamp)

Any suggestions or pointers as to what I'm missing would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What about a simple index on `timestamp`?

Comment: The table already has a simple index on timestamp, I'm trying to find something that will give me more speed, thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to make a single combined index?

Comment: You can prefix the query with `EXPLAIN` to see which indexes MySQL plans to use and where potential bottlenecks may exist.

Comment: @donnie I'm trying to get it to use an index rather than it using 'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort'.

Comment: @colin EXPLAIN says possible keys=timestamp, key=url ... go figure

Comment: Try separate indexes on the columns that it's suggesting, not a single combined index including all of them.

Comment: @Michael - try creating/removing different indexes and use EXPLAIN to see how it will use those indexes, which ones are most effective, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to rank URLs by popularity in a given time period.  Composite index on (URL, visitorid) would give you popularity.
Composite index on (timestamp,url) would give you the urls visited in period. Why not try both indexes, and do a join against an inline-view, something like this (not sure of the exact syntax for inline views in mysql):

```
       select distinct URL from log as Log1
                  where visitdatetime > x and visitdatetime< y


       join

       (select url, count(distinct visitorid) as DistinctVisitors
       from log
       group by url
        -- having count(distinct visitorid) > {some cutoff value greater than 1}
        -- try the composite index (url, visitorid, visitdate)
       having vistdate > x and visitdate < y 
       ) as Log2


       on Log1.url = log2.url

       order by DistinctVisitors desc
```

Comment: Unfortunately this approach does not work. Since the timestamp is not used to limit the Log2 query part, it basically counts visitorids for the whole table, since url from Log1 is can appear in any time-range, the join doesn't really do anything. If I add timestamp to log2, I'm basically back where I started. Also, I don't know beforehand what a sane cutoff value is, therefore I need to sort and limit to 100. Thanks for the thought though! Any other suggestions ?

Comment: How about composite index (url, visitor, visitdate) for the log2 inline view, and HAVING visitdate> x and visitdate < y and then you could get rid of LOG1.

Comment: Thanks. This works, but it's slightly slower than the original (leaving out crawl=0). The strange thing is, as soon as I add 'order by visitors desc limit 100', EXPLAIN says it uses key 'url' rather than the composite index you suggested

Comment: Try adding to the HAVING clause: and count(distinct visitorid) > 1.  Single-visit URLS may be numerous; no need to involve them in the sort. They're certainly not "popular", right?

Comment: Also, remove those other indexes so they're not candidates. You can always recreate them.

Answer (score 0):

Partition your access log into multiple tables, and only run this query over the tables within your date range.

Make summary tables with the data pre-aggregated on daily/weekly/monthly bases to cut down on the amount of data that has to be crunched to produce a report. So after the day's log files are imported, aggregate the data by dividing timestamp down to hour boundaries, then down to day boundaries etc.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent suggestion. I will definitely try splitting up the table into multiple ones. But consider this, say the data is already split into one table per month and it still has a gazillion records (which is the case). Now say I want to query a few days from that table. I can't use an aggregate for days, because a sum(daily visitors) will be different for that period than a count(distinct visitorid) over the actual period. Do you see any way to speed up the query given no other partitioning or pre-aggregation can be made ? i.e. a better index ?

Comment: I don't think there's a "golden bullet" answer of an index that will just make things work beautifully. Certainly I can't see one, hence my suggestions to attack the problem from a different angle.

Comment: If you aggregated (url,visitorid,count(*) as hits) for each day, you would then be able to use these daily aggregates to some extent, wouldn't you? i.e. don't try to aggregate completely up front, just reduce the amount of detail to the minimum required. Of course, if "hits" is always just 1 in that combination, that's not too useful... even so, you could reduce the width of that table considerably, and get better memory usage, although it looks like you've gone to some effort to narrow the table already.